# WPF C# - Extracting the player from webbrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, video, browser, flash

Purely as a training exercise, i am manipulating a WebBrowser through WPF application I have written.

I am opening a URL (a site that I do not own) that contains many elements and one of which is a player with a video inside that loads when click on the button that is in the middle of the page with a very simple piece of code like so:

```
var doc = webBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
                                                doc.all.item("confirm").Click();
```

I am then also hiding some elements such as the header div container like so:

```
var div = doc.all.item("file_title");
                                                div.style.display = "none";
```

This is working perfectly and launch the video and all BUT:
The scroll bars are annoying me and I can not seem to find a way to remove them from the WebBrowser.

I would also like to see if there is a way of extracting the player as a whole and not just extract the link as the player on the site is quite nice and the MediaElement in WPF just stinks when it comes to esthetics and it seems that VLCdotnet is not great when it comes to WPF. My thinking was to change the doc to ONLY contain the player and not any of the other elements of the page. Is this even doable?

Another way was to take the Flash player from the http://flowplayer.org/ site and incorporate it as a UserControl in my application and just load the URL of the video but i do not know who that can be done. Or if it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the `Style` of the `MediaElement`, the great thing about WPF is that you can alter it! If you can play the video in a native WPF control, you should definitely go that route, and style the player to more suit your needs.

Here is a great [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20478/A-simple-WPF-media-player-with-media-item-list) that creates a new style for the player. As you can see, WPF allows you to make it look just like you want. Getting it to look like the flowplayer is obviously going to take a bit of work, but in the long run it will be much better than trying to host an HTML video player in WPF.